# Как работает M-блочный поиск?

Tags: c, алгоритм

Как реализовать м-блочный поиск в массиве на С? Я перерыл пол-рунета и нашел только краткое описание, и то, оно кругом одинаковое.

Comment: Непонятный вопрос. Как следует понимать, "реализуйте для меня" или "объясните алгоритм"? Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, что неясно. Иначе ответ напрашивается: открываете текстовый редактор и пишете код на C

Comment: Пример М-блочного поиска на С. Как он работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласен с автором, ужас какой-то, все копируют текст из книжек "Громов Ю.Ю., Татаренко С.И. Программирование на языке СИ" и считают это ответом на вопрос =)

Вот алгоритм из моей домашней библиотеки =)

```
/* 
    M-блочный поиск. Предполагается, что исходный упорядоченный 
    (отсортированный) массив B длины N разбит на M подмассивов B1, B2,
    ..., BM длин N1, N2, ..., NM, таким образом, что B={ B1, B2 , .., BM}.
    Для нахождения ключа V, нужно сначала определить первый из списков Bi, 
    i=1,M, последний элемент которого больше V, а потом применить 
    последовательный поиск к списку Bi. 
*/

#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i, a[100], b[100], j, s = 0, k, x, z;
    int t;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        a[i] = 0, b[i] = 0;

    // Ввод массива (упорядоченного!)
    for (i = 0;; i++)   
    {
        printf("Enter A:");
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] == -1)
            break;
    }

    // Ввод длинн подмассивов
    for (j = 0;; j++)   
    {
        printf("Enter LEN");
        scanf("%d", &b[j]);
        if ((s += b[j]) >= i)
            break;
    }

    printf("Find:");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    j = 0;
    // printf("%d  %d  %d\n", k, a[k], b[j-1]);
    for (k = b[j++] - 1; (a[k] < x) && (k <= i); k += b[j++]) ; 
    if (k > i) {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    for (z = k - b[j - 1]; (z <= k); z++) {
        if (a[z] == x) {
            printf("Number:%d\n", z);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (z >= k)
        printf("Not found\n");
}
```

Comment: Прекрасно! Спасибо друг за помощь!!!